# all through the night / all over the night

Tags: prepositional-phrases, adverbial-phrases

Do these sentences imply on same meaning.
Are they interchangeable ?

> It rained all through the night.
>
> It rained all over the night.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It rained all through the night**.

This sentence is ok.  Your use of **all through** refers to the fact that it kept raining over a period of time i.e. the night.

You may also use **throughout** to give the same meaning.

e.g. It rained **throughout** the night.

The second sentence doesn't sound natural to me. However, the preposition **over**  can be used to express time.

e.g. She had been sick **over** the holidays. = during the holidays.

Given a choice, I would certainly choose the first sentence to express your meaning.